# What do we call this sentence constituent in English?

Tags: sentence-construction

Below is a short conversation between the host and Keanu Reeves.

Host:  "What **do you think** happens when we die, Keanu Reeves?"

Keanu Reeves: I know that the ones who love us will miss us."

What is the highlighted part in this sentence?

Comment: "Do you think" is not a grammatical unit, not a constituent, but part of the constituent "Do you think __ happens".

Answer (score 2):

It is a question.

In a statement you could have

> I think [something happens] when we die.

That is, "I think (embedded clause) when we die".

To convert this to a question, the usual inversion (with do support)  "do you think [something happens] when we die"  and fronted interogative replacing "something" "What do you think happens when we die?"

The word "happens" (or something similar) is needed, because "think" is followed by a clause, and we need a verb in this clause.  "happen" is a verb with very general meaning, and the answer can replace it with a more specific one.

Comment: " I think when we die" is not a correct sentence because the embedded clause is obligatory. In " What do you think happens when we die" , " do you think" looks like an inserted comment and it is optional because " What happens when we die" is a correct sentence.

Comment: Is that clearer?